# Unexpected performance when using a ProcessPool in Python

Tags: python, concurrency

I am trying to use `ProcessPoolExecutor` from Python
`concurrent.futures` package. However, I achieve very poor performance
and I cannot understand why.

My code looks like this:

```
import time
from itertools import product
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def myfunc(bundle):
    "A simple function which takes some time to complete."
    clock_start = time.clock()
    for _ in range(*bundle):
        lst = [[0., 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0]
                for x in range(6)]
        res = [t for t in product(*lst) if abs(sum(t) - 1.) < 1e-8]
    clock_elapsed = time.clock() - clock_start
    return clock_elapsed

def parallel(bundles, nworkers):
    "A function to dispatch execution between different workers."
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=nworkers) as executor:
        execgen = executor.map(myfunc, bundles)
        total_clock = 0.
        for _clock in execgen:
            total_clock += _clock
    print("mean iteration: {:.3f} s".format(total_clock / bundles[-1][-1]))
```

(The function `myfunc` has no interest as such but I expect the
execution to be linear in the number of iterations).

When I test this code on my computer (Python 3.6, Debian, 8 CPU), I
get the following results:

```
>>> parallel([(0, 60)], 1)
mean iteration: 3.660 s

>>> parallel([(0, 30), (30, 60)], 2)
mean iteration: 3.747 s

>>> parallel([(0, 20), (20, 40), (40, 60)], 3)
mean iteration: 4.413 s

>>> parallel([(0, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50), (50, 60)], 6)
mean iteration: 7.534 s
```

So, apparently, dividing the execution between 6 workers means that
one iteration takes in average twice as much time as it takes with one
worker. Since the iteration should be completely independant, I cannot
figure out why this is the case?

Comment: Here the overhead of setting up workers, and communicating is probably too much compared to the easy task.

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45256953/67579

Comment: Given the `myfunc` runs linear in the data, then typically do not expect much speedup, since serializing the item, communicating it, and communicating output also scales linear.

Comment: @Willemvanonsem Thank you for your answer. However, as you can see in the code, I do not measure the time taken to serialize data and communicate through the processes (the measurements are done inside `myfunc`), so it cannot be the explanation?

Comment: well if you do not have 6 cores, then this means that they will do timesharing, and it will require "process swaps" which are slow as well. Stopping a process on one CPU, and starting another one, of course happens quite fast, but still requires "some" work. The state of the CPU should be saved, the process scheduling might pick another process than a worker, and the CPU state of the process has to be loaded.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have 4 cores. I can understand the explanation for the case with 6 workers, but the case with 3 workers is also significantly slower per iteration than the case with 1 worker.

Comment: but meanwhile I guess you have other processes running, and these processes are distributed among the cores as well?

Comment: I have the OS running, but no other significant process. Furthermore, I encountered the same issue on a computer with 12 cores, 24 CPU (once again, with no other significant process running).

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't match your motivation. In all 4 runs of your code, your total_clock always is the **sum** time of finishing whole 60 calculation no matter how many cores you use. Theoretically, all 4 runs should return identical value without considering multiprocess cost(communication...). Obviously, this depends on the actually calculation workload no matter where(which core) it is run.

I believe you want to proof that multiprocess is time efficiency. Update code

```
print("mean iteration: {:.3f} s".format(total_clock / nworkers))
```

Or just feel and compare by human intuitive the time passed before those 4 runs return.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not understand what you are implying when you say "all 4 runs should return identical value". `multiprocessing` doc describes the `Pool` object as "a convenient means of parallelizing the execution of a function across multiple input values". Therefore, I expect the total execution to be faster when I use more cores...

Comment: @Latour. Maybe I shouldn't use identical. I mean identical-ish. The point is the time you print out is the sum time of multiple cores parallel running. Ex, in second run. you were using 2 cores and printing out the sum of time of two cores calculation which is almost 3.747/2 = 1.87 each which was run simultaneously. Yes, multiprocessing is true parallel. You used ~1.87s of your life but you print out the sum of 2 cores's ~1.87s and you saw 3.747.

Comment: I agree. However, in my example, `total_clock` is approximately equal to 220 s when I use one core, and 450 s when I use six cores. Using six cores is indeed faster (the calculation took 75 s), but what I do not understand is why the total time is bigger when I use more cores. As you said, all runs should return identical values...

Comment: The calculation time is more than I thought which means your computer probably not powerful enough. This doesn't bother you to use multiprocessing but os running worker become a heave load of cores. I agree @Willemvanonsem that overhead and communication could trigger this issue. The way to proof this is 1. find a faster machine 2. Make your test work more heavy so that your work become main part in cores comparing to os running.